# Toggle numbers not included inside the associative array in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way we can toggle to find out numbers that are not included inside the associative array set?

so if the data is

```
[options] => Array
                (
                    [1] => locality
                    [2] => postcode
                    [3] => dwelling_type
                    [4] => typical_value
                    [5] => dsr
                    [6] => dsr_summary
                    [13] => yield
                    [15] => search_dsr
                    [16] => sr
                    [17] => month
                    [18] => year
                )
```

How do I get an output of 7,8,9,10,11,12,14 programmically if the total count was 18?

SOLVED:

Actually my final answer is

```
$existingKeys = array_keys($options['User']['options']);
$Keys = range(0,18);
$missingKeys = array_diff($Keys,$existingKeys);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$existingKeys = array_keys($myArray['options']);
$minMaxrange = range(min($existingKeys),max($existingKeys));
$missingKeys = array_diff($minMaxrange,$existingKeys);
```

Comment: Sorry mate close but I wanted to get from another array which is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. you asked for an output of [7,8,9,10,11,12,14]... $missingKeys gives you that. If you want an output of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18] then $minMaxrange gives you that. If you're concerned that option 18 might be missing, then modify the definition of $minMaxrange... please look at the code and understand how it works.

Comment: I think you are correct. Sorry I should have explained better. I've got this at the end working! Thank you for your help I got this idea from you. $existingKeys = array_keys($options['User']['options']);
     $Keys = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18);
     $missingKeys = array_diff($Keys,$existingKeys);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $options = array( 0=>"zero", 2=>"two", 4=>"four", 8=>"height" );
    $optionsKeys = array_keys($options);

    $optionsMissingKeys = array();

    for ($i=0 ; $i < $optionsKeys[count($optionsKeys)-1] ; $i++) {

       if (in_array($i, $optionsKeys) == FALSE)
           array_push($optionsMissingKeys, $i);
    }

    print_r( $optionsMissingKeys );
```

Comment: @JohnKim should work in your case, sorry I did many modifications of my answer, this is the final result